# How can I align an sfsymbol with a Text view within a HStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to align an SFSymbol to a `Text` with both living in the same `HStack`. My problem is that when I use the parameter `alignment: .top`, the SFSymbol has a slight offset on the y axis relative to the Text. I expected the bottom of the symbol to be on the same pixel line than the the bottom of the first line of `Text` view.

I understand this is not how it should behave, but I also assumed that since both views are in the same frame (?) they should be aligned the same way with `alignment: .top`.

**Here is the relevant code**

```swift
HStack(alignment: .top) {
  Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
    .foregroundStyle(.purple)
    .font(.system(size:15))
  Text
    .foregroundColor(.purple)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
}
```

**The result on my iPhone XR**

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WwLj.jpg)

I tried to remove the `alignment` parameter and play with the `frame` modifier of the `Text` to have a max height of infinity and to be aligned on the top. I thought that the `Text` will be pushed to the top and be levelled with the `Image`, but the offset persists.

**EDIT**

This is how I would want it to look but with the symbol.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OObeL.jpg)

Comment: `HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline)`

Comment: ... and I would use `.font(.callout)` rather than the hard-coded font size.

Comment: This is the one thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`.firstTextBaseline`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/verticalalignment/firsttextbaseline) alignment. This aligns the image with the bottom (more specifically, the "baseline") of the first line of the text.

```
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
    ....
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works great indeed thanks for the tip!